# Download Excel using Maatwebsite

Tags: excel, laravel

My output array after a select query is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nonrem_id] => 1
            [nonrem_bank_accno] => 001-4537145-46
            [nonrem_bank_name] => Axis
            [nonrem_uniq_num] => BEUP3832618
            [nonrem_receipt_number] => 123456
            [nonrem_gl_date] => 2017-02-01
            [nonrem_remit_date] => 2017-02-01
            [nonrem_customer_name] => ABC
            [nonrem_payment_method] => WIRE
            [nonrem_ustatus] => NEGOTIABLE
            [nonrem_currency] => EUR
            [nonrem_trans_amount] => 74.97
            [nonrem_acct_amt] => 65.31999999999999
            [nonrem_variance] => 5.0E-11
            [nonrem_cstatus] => Closed
            [nonrem_assigned] => ssc.BERcptcreation
            [nonrem_autoclosed] => Yes
            [nonrem_created_date] => 2017-04-28 09:50:39
            [nonrem_lastupdate] => 2017-04-28 11:26:21
            [nonrem_created_by_name] => ILANGOVAN Thilagam
            [comments] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [nonrem_id] => 2
            [nonrem_bank_accno] => 001-4537145-46
            [nonrem_bank_name] => BNP PARIBAS FORTIS
            [nonrem_uniq_num] => BEUP3836443
            [nonrem_receipt_number] => 67890
            [nonrem_gl_date] => 2017-02-01
            [nonrem_remit_date] => 2017-02-01
            [nonrem_customer_name] => XYZ
            [nonrem_payment_method] => WIRE
            [nonrem_ustatus] => NEGOTIABLE
            [nonrem_currency] => EUR
            [nonrem_trans_amount] => 74.97
            [nonrem_acct_amt] => 
            [nonrem_variance] => 5.0E-11
            [nonrem_cstatus] => Closed
            [nonrem_assigned] => ssc.BERcptcreation
            [nonrem_autoclosed] => Yes
            [nonrem_created_date] => 2017-04-28 09:50:39
            [nonrem_lastupdate] => 2017-04-28 11:26:21
            [nonrem_created_by_name] => ILANGOVAN Thilagam
            [comments] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [nonrem_id] => 3
            [nonrem_bank_accno] => 001-4537145-46
            [nonrem_bank_name] => Axis
            [nonrem_uniq_num] => BEUP3832700
            [nonrem_receipt_number] => 123456
            [nonrem_gl_date] => 2017-02-01
            [nonrem_remit_date] => 2017-02-01
            [nonrem_customer_name] => ABC
            [nonrem_payment_method] => WIRE
            [nonrem_ustatus] => NEGOTIABLE
            [nonrem_currency] => EUR
            [nonrem_trans_amount] => 74.97
            [nonrem_acct_amt] => 65.31999999999999
            [nonrem_variance] => 5.0E-11
            [nonrem_cstatus] => Open
            [nonrem_assigned] => ssc.beappayment@cma-cgm.com
            [nonrem_autoclosed] => No
            [nonrem_created_date] => 2017-05-04 11:19:01
            [nonrem_lastupdate] => 2017-05-04 11:19:01
            [nonrem_created_by_name] => ILANGOVAN Thilagam
            [comments] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [nonrem_id] => 4
            [nonrem_bank_accno] => 001-4537145-46
            [nonrem_bank_name] => BNP PARIBAS FORTIS
            [nonrem_uniq_num] => BEUP3836701
            [nonrem_receipt_number] => 67890
            [nonrem_gl_date] => 2017-02-01
            [nonrem_remit_date] => 2017-02-01
            [nonrem_customer_name] => XYZ
            [nonrem_payment_method] => WIRE
            [nonrem_ustatus] => NEGOTIABLE
            [nonrem_currency] => EUR
            [nonrem_trans_amount] => 74.97
            [nonrem_acct_amt] => 60
            [nonrem_variance] => 5.0E-11
            [nonrem_cstatus] => Open
            [nonrem_assigned] => ssc.BERcptcreation
            [nonrem_autoclosed] => No
            [nonrem_created_date] => 2017-05-04 11:19:02
            [nonrem_lastupdate] => 2017-05-04 11:19:02
            [nonrem_created_by_name] => ILANGOVAN Thilagam
            [comments] => 
        )

)
```

My headers array is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Ref id
    [1] => Bank Account Number
    [2] => Bank Name
    [3] => Unique number
    [4] => Receipt Number
    [5] => GL Date
    [6] => Remit Date
    [7] => Customer Name
    [8] => Payment Method
    [9] => Uploaded Status
    [10] => Currency
    [11] =>  Transaction Amount
    [12] => Accounted Amount
    [13] => Variance
    [14] => Status
    [15] => Assigned
    [16] => Auto Closed
    [17] => Uploaded Date
    [18] => LastUpdated Date
    [19] => Uploaded By
    [20] => Comments
)
```

I am using the Maatwebsite for Excel download..
I do get the downloaded file but the issues is I want the headers to be from the headers array rather it takes the indexes of the Select query resultant array.

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

Take heading in the seperate array and pass values of it as array to insert heading row..

```
$headings = array_values($heading_array);//your heading array
$sheet->appendRow($headings);
```

after iterate your loop to insert other rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this why.. below example is for 5 column ..

```
$row_count = 0; 
$obj_time = Carbon\Carbon::now();
$current_time = $obj_time->toDateTimeString();
$filename = 'report_'.$current_time;
Excel::create($filename, function($excel) use($row_count, $data){
  $excel->sheet('Data', function($sheet) use($row_count, $data){
    $sheet->setOrientation('landscape');
    $sheet->cells('A1', function($cells) {
        $cells->setFontWeight('bold');
        $cells->setFontSize(14);
    });         
    $sheet->setHeight(3, 25);
      $sheet->cells('A3:E3', function($cells) {
        $cells->setBackground('#f2f2f2');
        $cells->setFontColor('#000000');
        $cells->setFontWeight('bold');
        $cells->setFontSize(12);
        $cells->setValignment('center');
      });   
      $sheet->row(3, array(
        'Ref id', 'Bank Account Number', 'Bank Name', 'Unique number', 'Receipt Number'
      ));
      $row_count = 4;
        for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++)
        {
          $sheet->row($row_count, array(
            $data[$i]->nonrem_id, $data[$i]->nonrem_bank_accno,   $data[$i]->nonrem_bank_name,$data[$i]->nonrem_uniq_num, $data[$i]->nonrem_receipt_number
          ));
          $row_count++;
        }
        $row = $row_count-1;
        $sheet->setBorder('A3:E'.$row, 'thin');     
        $sheet->cells('L3:E'.$row, function($cells) {
          $cells->setAlignment('center');
        });

        $row_count++; 
  });   
})->export('xls');
```